# How to fix regex "Redundent character escape..." problem around multiple backslashes(\)?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a question about Java Regex and I just got confused by online resources.

Since this code was not writter by me and I only receive potential error and improvement suggestion from IDE. I have commented what IDE gave me in after line. I also do not have a current result for reference as this method was not used anywhere.

Right now, I assume these lines want to sanitize string from `\"xyz"\` to `"xyz"`.

The jdk is Java17 in case that might affect the compiler.

```
private String sanitizeString(String message) {
    message = message.replaceAll("\\\"", "\""); // Redundant character escape '\\\"' in RegExp 
    message = message.replaceAll("\"\\", "\""); // Illegal/unsupported escape sequence
    return message; 
 }
```

Thank you for reading. Any knowledge and correction would be appreciated.

After I read some [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), I came up with the regex for 2nd line might be `\\\"\\\\`. But why is IDE still giving warning about "Redundant ..." around first half `\\\"` ?

Comment: `"\\\""` is a ``\"`` pattern which is equal to just `"`. At regex101, use the *Code generator*, it will solve all your problems. And another hint: to just replace ``\"`` with `"`, you do not need regex, use `message.replace("\\\"", "\"")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. I just used the code generator and it helps.